# What happened to Xboard?

Tags: software-installation

"Unable to install xboard as not supported"
I installed it a month ago.  Had to delete it two days ago since the commands suddenly weren't working (although the mouse actions were).  The program has been around for more than ten years.  Did somebody change it?
I get this in Terminal:

```
owner@owner-Lenovo-ideapad-110S-11IBR:~$ sudo apt-get install xboard
[sudo] password for owner: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xboard is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'xboard' has no installation candidate
owner@owner-Lenovo-ideapad-110S-11IBR:~$
```

Comment: Are Universe repositories enabled?

Answer (score 0):

As Kulfy stated earlier in the comment section the desired package is available through the universe repository. In both [bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages) and [cosmic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/allpackages) it is part of the list of available packages if you enable the mentioned source.